# change text in one button

Tags: jquery

I have several buttons with same text inside - each button opens a containing div when clicked. 
Problem is, that i cant make text change only on the SINGLE button clicked - when i click a button the text changes simultaneously on ALL buttons.

Does anyone know how do change the text in only the button clicked?

This is the code i have so far - the jQuery is not working correctly:

HTML

```
<div class="btn"> SHOW </div>
        <div class="pre_hide" style="background: blue">          
            <h5>BOX 1</h5>
        </div> <!-- END OF pre_hide -->       
<br>

<div class="btn"> SHOW </div>
        <div class="pre_hide" style="background: blue">          
            <h5>BOX 2</h5>
        </div> <!-- END OF pre_hide -->       
<br>

<div class="btn"> SHOW </div>
        <div class="pre_hide" style="background: blue">          
            <h5>BOX 3</h5>
        </div> <!-- END OF pre_hide -->
```

JQuery

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    if(event.target === this) { // THIS IS NOT WORKING !!
        if ($(this).text() == "HIDE") {  
            $('.btn').text("SHOW");
            $(this).next('.pre_hide').css({'display': 'none'});
        }
        else {  
            $('.btn').text("HIDE");
            $(this).next('.pre_hide').css({'display': 'block'});
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

this should work:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == "HIDE") {  
        $(this).text("SHOW");
        $(this).next('.pre_hide').css({'display': 'none'});
    }   
    else {  
        $(this).text("HIDE");
        $(this).next('.pre_hide').css({'display': 'block'});
    } 
});
```

Comment: yes, with $(this).next('.pre_hide') it would work too

Comment: i was asking about `.css({'display': 'none'});` vs `hide()`

Comment: yeah yeah, your line should be $(this).next('.pre_hide').hide()

Answer (score 2):

You made the change over the `$('.btn')` not `$(this)` that's why you change all the buttons texts.

Try change this:

```
$('.btn').text("SHOW");
```

To:

```
$(this).text("SHOW");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

        if ($(this).text() == "HIDE") {  
            $('.btn').text("SHOW");
            $(this).next('.pre_hide').css({'display': 'none'});
        }
        else {  
            $('.btn').text("HIDE");
            $(this).next('.pre_hide').css({'display': 'block'});
        }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var elm = $(this); //touch DOM once. she is too precious
    if (elm.text() == "HIDE") {
        elm.text("SHOW").next(".pre_hide").hide();
    } else {
        elm.text("HIDE").next(".pre_hide").show();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/TkTL9/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn', $(this)).text('SHOW');
```

or

```
$('.btn', $(this)).text('HIDE');
```